# Blackboard server - issue with restarting

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7, servlet-3.0, blackboard

SEVERE: The web application [/webapps/bb-nautilus-BBLEARN] appears to have started a thread named [MessageQueueHandler-bb-nautilus-content-blitz-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

Comment: And the question is ???

Comment: The above mentioned is the error which I am facing. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application starts all kinds of stuff (registering jdbc drivers, starting threads, ...) when it is fired up, it is the responsibility of that application to also clean up after itself when it is stopped.

Are you the author of this application ?  Correct your code.  Not the author of this application ?  Submit a bug report.

In the latter case, until the bug is addressed it might be possible to add a ServletContextListener of your own making to the deployment.  But clearing up leftover Threads from "foreign" code is at any rate going to require you to figure out how to find those Thread objects and then subsequently stop() them, which is a deprecated method.

Answer (score 1):

MessageQueue may be busy doing something strange.  It refuses to exit.  So, reboot the server and try starting Bb Learn after that.  Post the new error after you know that no part of Bb Learn was running after a failed app restart.